# What is a fix for manually renamed files in a git project?

Tags: git, github

I had two files `a.rb` and `b.rb`. I manually renamed them in Sublime Text to `c.rb` and `d.rb` and made some changes to those files and pushed my branch to the remote repository using these commands:

```
git add
git commit -m "message"
git push origin branch-name
```

I should have done a `git mv` instead instead of manually renaming it.

Now I need a proper way to fix this issue so that others don't have merge conflicts.
The only way I can think of is:

```
git checkout branch.
git rm c.rb.
git mv a.rb c.rb.
copy paste my old c.rb code to a.rb.
```

Is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: Roll back to the point before the manual change, git mv the a and b.rb's to c and d.rb, then paste in changes to remove chance of merge conflicts.

Comment: you can call `git rm` on an already deleted file, no need to rollback

Comment: It's incidental that this involves Ruby, so I'm removing the ruby tag.

Comment: Unless the changes you made were very big, Git should be able to detect this as a move. `git mv` won't help, to fix a broken history it'd be best to commit the move and the edits separately. That said, you've already published the branch, you shouldn't really rewrite what's there anymore unless you're absolutely sure nobody else has grabbed it yet.

Comment: Did you run `git add` or `git add .`?  `git add` alone doesn't add any files.  `git add .` would have added only the new files `c.rb` and `d.rb`.  Is this what you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a soft reset of our branch "Head" just before the commit. Then use the `git mv` command to rename the file.

If you don't want to do the above, then you can just delete the files "a.rb" and "b.rb":

```
$ git ls-files --deleted | xargs,
```

This will add the deleted files. Commit the change and push it so if the collaborators in the project pull it, the new files are pulled in and the previous ones are deleted.

Comment: Don't bother. Git doesn't actually track renames. See @jcoder's answer.

Answer (score 7):

git mv doesn't do anything special. It just does the git add and the git rm for you.
The fact that it is a moved file rather than an add and delete isn't recorded anywhere, it's inferred when you request a log.

All you need to do is make sure that you did a "git add" for the new name which I think you did, and a "git rm" on the existing file.

Comment: git doesn't even record a rename/copy/move at all.  Renames/copies/moves are based on the similarity of files.  The level of similarity required to indicate a file is a rename or copy is configurable.  It is occasionally useful to adjust this value when trying to see how chunks of code were moved around during a big refactoring.  See the --find-renames and --find-copies options on the diff command for more details.

Comment: Ah, neat. After manually renaming, but before committing, I just tried a `git  rm` followed by a `git add` and `git status` now magically shows that a rename took place (purely from the file statuses and contents).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you previously pushed new files `c.rb` and `d.rb`, your workspace HEAD points to this commit, and files `a.rb` and `b.rb` are deleted in your workspace:

```
[dmahar@dmahar rename3]$ git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at d77decf Rename 'a.rb' to 'c.rb' and 'b.rb' to 'd.rb'.
[dmahar@dmahar rename3]$ ls
a.rb  b.rb  c.rb  d.rb
[dmahar@dmahar rename3]$ git rm c.rb d.rb
rm 'c.rb'
rm 'd.rb'
[dmahar@dmahar rename3]$ ls
a.rb  b.rb
[dmahar@dmahar rename3]$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    c.rb
#   deleted:    d.rb
#
[dmahar@dmahar rename3]$ git commit --message "Delete 'c.rb' and d.rb'."
[master 60f97ab] Delete 'c.rb' and d.rb'.
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 c.rb
 delete mode 100644 d.rb
[dmahar@dmahar rename3]$ ls
a.rb  b.rb
[dmahar@dmahar rename3]$ git mv a.rb c.rb
[dmahar@dmahar rename3]$ git mv b.rb d.rb
[dmahar@dmahar rename3]$ git commit --message "Rename 'a.rb' to 'c.rb' and 'b.rb' to 'd.rb', again."
[master 8182195] Rename 'a.rb' to 'c.rb' and 'b.rb' to 'd.rb', again.
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename a.rb => c.rb (100%)
 rename b.rb => d.rb (100%)
[dmahar@dmahar rename3]$ ls
c.rb  d.rb
[dmahar@dmahar rename3]$ git log -M --summary
commit 8182195c1494541ab1dcaa97607ce4dc8b277d56
Author: Derek Mahar <derek.mahar@intelerad.com>
Date:   Thu May 30 15:21:12 2013 -0400

    Rename 'a.rb' to 'c.rb' and 'b.rb' to 'd.rb', again.

 rename a.rb => c.rb (100%)
 rename b.rb => d.rb (100%)

commit 60f97abb56e5b1e32d02dfb8ff14400910d4fef4
Author: Derek Mahar <derek.mahar@intelerad.com>
Date:   Thu May 30 15:20:11 2013 -0400

    Delete 'c.rb' and d.rb'.

 delete mode 100644 c.rb
 delete mode 100644 d.rb

commit d77decf9863fb1b4f8a2902becf687e6ececf4ce
Author: Derek Mahar <derek.mahar@intelerad.com>
Date:   Thu May 30 12:59:15 2013 -0400

    Rename 'a.rb' to 'c.rb' and 'b.rb' to 'd.rb'.

 create mode 100644 c.rb
 create mode 100644 d.rb

commit 219ce73f40d46690d77751fccd86b7c5a60b0d7d
Author: Derek Mahar <derek.mahar@intelerad.com>
Date:   Thu May 30 12:58:24 2013 -0400

    Add 'a.rb' and 'b.rb'.

 create mode 100644 a.rb
 create mode 100644 b.rb
```